# Sort MySQL query with JOIN

Tags: mysql, join, phpmyadmin

I'm getting an error when I try to order my column on phpmyadmin result.
This is the error:

[image]

My query is:

```
SELECT Cliente.Codigo, Cliente.Nome, Contato.Nome, Grupo.Nome FROM Cliente JOIN Grupo ON ( Grupo.codigo = Cliente.Codigo_Grupo ) JOIN Contato ON ( Contato.Codigo_Cliente = Cliente.Codigo ) GROUP BY Cliente.Codigo ASC
```

The ORDER BY was added automatically, when I click on title of column.
Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Comment: What column do you want to sort by?

Comment: I'd like to sort when it is selected on phpmyadmin or in jqgrid. It is why I didn't put any ORDER BY in my query.

Comment: I believe the engine will do a sort regardless. You need to specify a column to sort if you do not want an engine sort.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect this to be wrongly-gerated SQL: Try

```
SELECT Cliente.Codigo AS Codigo, Cliente.Nome, Contato.Nome AS Contato, Grupo.Nome AS Grupo 
FROM Cliente 
JOIN Grupo ON ( Grupo.codigo = Cliente.Codigo_Grupo ) 
JOIN Contato ON ( Contato.Codigo_Cliente = Cliente.Codigo ) 
GROUP BY Cliente.Codigo 
ORDER BY `Grupo` ASC
LIMIT 0,30
```

After discussion in the comments, it turns out, that an underlying bug in a framework is the culprit:
- Without alias on `Grupo.Nome` it will choke on the `Nome` part
- With alias on `Grupo.Name` it will choke on the alias

There is a really, really dirty way around this - but please be aware, that it is a workaround (at best), not a solution

Do this once:

```
CREATE VIEW GrupoWorkaround SELECT Grupo.*,Grupo.Nome AS Grupo FROM Grupo
```

This will create a parallel view.

No change your Query to

```
SELECT Cliente.Codigo AS Codigo, Cliente.Nome, Contato.Nome AS Contato, GrupoWorkaround.Grupo
FROM Cliente 
JOIN GrupoWorkaround ON ( GrupoWorkaround.codigo = Cliente.Codigo_Grupo ) 
JOIN Contato ON ( Contato.Codigo_Cliente = Cliente.Codigo ) 
GROUP BY Cliente.Codigo 
ORDER BY `Grupo` ASC
LIMIT 0,30
```

in fact replaceing `Grupo` with `GrupoWorkaround` and thus obliverating the need for an alias.

Comment: Eugen, it works fine, but I have a problem cause I'm using JQGrid, and the search doesn't work because the grid does like phpmyadmin, makes the order queries in runtime, with Grupo.Grupo, instead only 'Grupo' or Grupo.Nome. Did you get it?

Comment: This is a bug in SQL generation. Try to keep `Grupo.Nome` without an alias (=Drop the "AS Grupo" part)

Comment: Withou Alias it works perfectly, but I can't keep without them because I have "Nome" in all tables. That's my problem. I'm trying to find any way to do this query without Alias since yesterday, but I couldn't find it yet.

Comment: Then you need a REALLY dirty trick, updating my answer ... done